# Vector2 equivalent in c++?

Tags: c#, c++, xna, cocos2d-x

Hi I'm porting my game from c#/xna to c++/cocos2d-x and I was trying to find an equivalent to Vector2. I did find a couple such as b2Vec2, I'm just not sure which one I should use because I need it to be cross platform and not bound to a specific operating system.

Comment: `struct Vector2 { float x; float y; };`

Comment: What about the `Vector2` [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2_members)?

Comment: Zeta, c++ have not .net classes, you must write youself

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do something cross-platform *and* use cocos2d...

Comment: Just because C++ does not have .net classes, doesn't mean you have to write everything yourself.  There are other libraries besides .net in the world.

Comment: @Peter You do realize cocos2d-x is written in c++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you're looking for is the poorly-named* [`CCPoint`](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/d2/df3/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_point.html) class. Cocos2d-x is a direct port of the API of Cocos2d, which was designed for Objective C. And since Objective C doesn't have operator overloading, neither does Cocos2d-x, even though it's written in C++ where operator overloading exists. So you have to [use free-functions to do vector operations](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/dc/d53/_c_c_point_extension_8h.html#).

*: In case you're wondering *why* it is poorly named, "vector" covers the concept of "point" (a position within a space) and "direction" (a direction in a space). A vector can be either of these. Adding vectors has a specific meaning geometrically, as does subtracting them, multiplying them, taking the length, etc. Adding a point to another point is nonsense, geometrically. You can only add vector *directions*, not positions. You can transform positions into another space, but you don't do that by adding one position to another.